# How to split a string into 2D array and apply operator to array element in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Here is the string we have:

```
string = 'project_manager, foreman, buyer'
```

We would like to convert it into a 2D array like this:

[[I18n.t('project_manager'), 'project_manager'], [I18n.t('foreman'), 'foreman'], [I18n.t('buyer'), 'buyer']]

The 2D array will be fed into Rails view and create a drop-down list for selection. The I18n.t() is for translation of the word if language other than English is specified.

Comment: In either of the answers, if the elements are reliably separated with `", "` instead of `","` then you could split with that and lose the `strip` or `squish`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = 'project_manager, foreman, buyer'
string.split(",").map{|x| [  I18n.t(x.strip)   ,  x.strip  ] }
```

split(",") method returns the array (sub-string split into it with delimiter ","),

```
["project_manager", " foreman", " buyer"]
```

map method iterates over each element of the above array , maps each element to the new element computed and returned from the block and finally returns the new array with new elements. In our case the new elements are themselves array hence we are getting a 2D array as a result.

Finally, 'strip' method removes all blank spaces around a string if present.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Here is the 2D array generated:  [["translation missing: zh-CN.project_manager", "project_manager"], ["translation missing: zh-CN.foreman", "foreman"], ["translation missing: zh-CN
buyer", "buyer"]]

Answer (score 4):

Do as below, by first [squishing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish), then *splitting* the string into an `Array`, then use the `Array#map` method on it.

```
string = 'project_manager, foreman, buyer'
string.squish.split(',').map { |elem| [I18n.t(elem), elem] }
```

Tried in the Rails console :-

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Rails/model_prac> rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.4)
2.1.2 :001 > "   tr  ".squish
 => "tr"
2.1.2 :002 > string = 'project_manager, foreman, buyer'
 => "project_manager, foreman, buyer"
2.1.2 :003 > string.squish.split(',').map { |elem| [I18n.t(elem), elem] }
 => [["translation missing: en.project_manager", "project_manager"], ["translation missing: en. foreman", " foreman"], ["translation missing: en. buyer", " buyer"]]
2.1.2 :004 >
```

Comment: Just about to mention this and you beat me to it! :)

Comment: Why not just `I18n.t(elem)`? What OP asks for makes little sense

Comment: @MichalSzyndel You are true.. I just checked the _documentation_.

Comment: Here is the array it created: [["translation missing: zh-CN.project_manager, foreman, buyer", "project_manager, foreman, buyer"]]

Comment: Now works. Squish may still leave whitespace in the output array as squish may keep one whitespace. Many thanks.